# Pretty way to inject Spring properties to object not managed by Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application and I'm using a third party library. There's no constructor, everything is configured and instantiated inside of this library. 
I can add some custom behavior by creating a class. What I need is to add my Spring properties to this class.

Here's the class:

```
public static class CustomClass implements ExternalClass {

    @Override
    public Object create() {

    //Here I would like to inject my properties.    

    }

}
```

I'm looking for a pretty approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Configurable` annotation on this class to make it possible to inject `Environment` or directly a property via `@Value` as usual. [This is the documentation of this annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-atconfigurable).

```
@Configurable
public static class CustomClass implements ExternalClass {
 //..
 //inject Environment to get property or via @Value as usual
 //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create this class in your project

```
@Component public class IOC implements ApplicationContextAware {
private static ApplicationContext ctx;
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.ctx = applicationContext;
}
public static ApplicationContext getCtx() {
    return ctx;
}
```

}

then call

```
Environment environment = IOC.getCtx().getEnvironment();
```

in the create method to get your properties